# The sum of filtered results do not match with the total on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Using filters in the segments on Google Analytics does not match with the total.

I am looking at the Audience in Google Analytics for the website, typically following metrics;
- Users
- Sessions
- Pageviews

The website has 5 sub-directories and 2 of them have a big impact on traffic due to seasonality/event. Let's say those two pages are called "page A" and "page B".
To observe a difference caused by the pages in these sub-directories, I created 3 different custom segments on GA, such as;

1. include only page A
2. include only page B
3. exclude page A and B

[This is an exmaple of how I created a custom segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q9L4.png)

I expected to see that the sum of filtered results (1+2+3)  will match with the numbers I see in "Audience" (Total Users, Sessions, Pageviews). But the sum in all the metrics are about 5% smaller (e.g. the report says Pageviews is 2780 but the sum of 3 segments says 2110).

Can anyone help me understand why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the settings of segment 3? How the exclusion is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If segment 1 must include sessions with page A, it includes sessions with page A with/out page B. Vice-versa, if segment 2 must include sessions with page B, it includes sessions with/out page A.

You need the 2nd page exclusion in both, and 4 segments after all to get the sum:

1. include page A **AND** exclude page B
2. include page B **AND** exclude page A
3. include page A **AND** include page B
4. exclude page A **AND** exclude page B